# Print all text in-between two characters

Tags: java, indexof

I want to print a specific part of text from a text file.
For example :

> number)street)city)state)country)

I want to print from `)` to `)` so that any street name or country can go into the text file. What I have done is:

- I have tried connecting scanner to the file and creating a while loop with `.hasNextLine();`
- Then creating a String for the whole of the text file `String line = textscanner.nextLine();`
- Then to print out `country` for example, I would create a substring `System.out.print(line.substring(25));`

However, this won't work if there are different street or country names in the file. How do I make it so that it will print anything from the `)` to `)`?

Comment: Can you give a couple of example lines of the actual file?

Comment: use hasNext(); method instead of hasNextLine();

Answer (score 2):

You have to take advantage of Java's `split()` method, which accepts a specified string of text to use as separators/delimiters to words, which are often commas, like in .csv files. I'm going to skip the part about reading the file and just use this string as an example and put the words into an array:

```
String line = "number)street)city)state)country)";
String[] words = line.split("\\)");
```

Note in your case you must use double backslashes or the compiler will throw an error saying no matching parentheses.

Comment: like this ?



String[] words = line.split(")");
String part1 = words[0];
String part2 = words[1];
System.out.print(part1 + part2);

Comment: You can't split directly on `")"` like that you need to use `("\\)")` as it will throw an error saying unmatched closing parenthesis